# Setting the height of ObjectChoiceField in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I have used the [ObjectChoiceField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ObjectChoiceField.html) in my application. The choice are very long, mostly the choices are of two line which increases the height of the `ObjectChoiceField` and makes my UI unstable. I had used "**single line = true**" property in **Android** which allows long text line to show in ellipses(...).

Can I do that in BlackBerry as don't want to change the height on run time. Also I don't want to use custom `ObjectChoiceField`. please suggest me according to my conditions what can I do.

*Currently I am using follwing code.*

```java
ObjectChoiceField _productLineOCF =new ObjectChoiceField("",_productLineArray,plSetTo1,Field.FIELD_RIGHT){
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setMinimalWidth(width - 61);
        super.layout(width, height);
    }
};
```

*Sample output of the above code:*

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```java
String choices[] = {
        "Choice 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "Choice 2",
        "Choice 3" };

long styleBit = Field.FIELD_RIGHT | ObjectChoiceField.FORCE_SINGLE_LINE;

ObjectChoiceField ocf = new ObjectChoiceField("", choices, 0, styleBit) {
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setMinimalWidth(width - 61);
        super.layout(width, height);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanx a lot dear, you are really great mentor for me. the "styleBit" worked for me. I need to learn a lot and I am learning. Thanx again to you and developers community.